# AttributeError : 'FigureManagerBase' object has no attribut 'window'

Tags: python, matplotlib, window

I had been used the python code below well but when I re-installed Anaconda python 2.7 ver., that code has an error. Why this happened?

```py
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom=0.05, left=0.05, right=0.95, wspace=0.55, hspace=0.2)
plt.figtext(0.5, 0.95, str(os.path.basename(self.filepath)),ha='center', color='black', weight='bold', size='small')
mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mngr.window.setGeometry(810, 30, 800, 800)
show()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hyeyoung\Desktop\20200211MHyeyoung.py", line 4482, in onOpenImageFile
    self.ShowAFewFrames()

  File "C:\Users\hyeyoung\Desktop\20200211MHyeyoung.py", line 4509, in ShowAFewFrames
    mngr.window.setGeometry(810,30,800, 800)

AttributeError: 'FigureManagerBase' object has no attribute 'window'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Anaconda python ver. : 2.7
matplotlib ver. :2.2.2

please give me an answer. thx
```

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message. Why are you using Python 2?

Comment: Also, looking at the docs for [`FigureManagerBase`](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureManagerBase), I can’t see a `window` attribute, so that checks out.

Comment: I attach the entire error to the post. Because the python code is 2.7 ver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that `plt.get_current_fig_manager()` returns an object that has a `window` attribute. That would only be the case when using the `Qt4Agg`, or `Qt5Agg` (or `Qt4Cairo` / `Qt5Cairo`) backend, because in that case the figure manager is a `FigureManagerQT`, which is a subclass of `QtWidgets.QWidget` and a Qt widget has a `window` attribute.

Hence if you want to use that attribute, make sure to use the respective backend, e.g.

```
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i do this, it works for me!!:)